# I have the Pixel 3, when using glsurfaceview, in portrait mode the top has rounded edges, but the bottom does not. How do I fix this?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, rounded-corners, glsurfaceview

I double checked another popular 3d game and noticed they had rounded corners on all sides.  How do I get rounded corners on all sides when using glsurfaceview?

Comment: Rounded edges of what?

Comment: The display has rounded corners.  The top side appears to be physically rounded in hardware.  The bottom side appears to be a regular 90 degree corner but made to look rounded in software.  I'm trying to figure out if there is an api call to make android render the bottom corners as rounded.  With my use of glsurfaceview the bottom corners are a 90 degree angle.

Comment: Does your app have the system buttons (back button etc) permanently visible? If so, maybe you need to look into [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive)

Comment: @Columbo thank you.  Immersive mode was the answer.